# How to get all tags from specific branch using LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

From documentation listing all tags:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/repo"))
{
   foreach (Tag t in repo.Tags)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(t.FriendlyName);
   }
}
```

But i need to list only tags from specific branch. Is this possible with LibGit2Sharp?